# Ubuntu configuration issue for different port with multiple site

Tags: 14.04, apache2

Issue in setting up different port for multiple sites in my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS using LAMP.

Below are the configurations i have used:

**etc\apache2\ports.conf**

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

#NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
Listen 1000

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**etc\apache2\sites-available\000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost:80>
    //Default config here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1000>
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/My_Site
<Directory /var/www/html/My_Site>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
 </Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is :

a) if i **service apache2 reload**  the configurations given above isnt reflecting in **etc\apache2\sites-enabled\000-default.conf**

b) My custom port 1000 seems to be listening, but the apache2's default homepage is loading by hitting by IP.

1) Is my document root :  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/My_Site correct?

Suggestion appreciated!!

Comment: `<VirtualHost>` should of course be `<VirtualHost *:80>`, no?

Comment: I have updated the answer @Alex... but i need my port 1000 to hit my specified document root

Comment: I understand that you want to have two virtual hosts, one listening on port 80 and one on port 1000. See Virtual Hosts Examples -- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html --in Apache documentation.